# How to split a long table into pages with multicolumn in each page?

Tags: longtable

I have a very long table (64 rows) with 14 columns. I split it with lontable package, but it keeps error for multicolumn syntax. Any suggestion please? part of the table is here:

And I couldn't figure out how to put "continued from the previous page" in between?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccccccc|ccccccc}
\caption{\textbf{State Table for the proposed network}}\\
 \label{table: state table proposed net.} 

\multicolumn{14}{c}{n=0} \\
\hline 


e & f & o & h & c & g & r & E & F & O & H & C & G & R  \\ 
\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%1
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%2
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%3
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%4
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%5
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%6
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%7
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%% 8 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%9
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%10
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%11
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%12
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%%13
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%14
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%%15
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\   
    %%%%%%%16
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post _complete_ documents from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so people can run your code and see what error you get.  You can edit your example to add the missing details (use the `{}` button for code sections as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `\\` after `\caption{}` also do not put `longtable` in a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccccccc|ccccccc}
\caption{State Table for the proposed network%
\label{table: state table proposed net.} }\\
\multicolumn{14}{c}{n=0} \\
\hline 
e & f & o & h & c & g & r & E & F & O & H & C & G & R  \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{State Table for the proposed network (continued)}\\
\multicolumn{14}{c}{n=0} \\
\hline 
e & f & o & h & c & g & r & E & F & O & H & C & G & R  \\ 
\hline
\endhead
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%1
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%2
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%3
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%4
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%5
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%6
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%7
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%% 8 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%9
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%10
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%11
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
    %%%%%%%12
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%%13
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\  
    %%%%%%14
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    %%%%%%%15
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\   
    %%%%%%%16
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I modified them, but gives me this error: ! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit  \@multispan

Comment: It was ok with tabular, but it can't split into the pages

Comment: *How* did you modify them? Please post the **complete** code of a minimal example. `longtable` has no problem with multicolumn set ups. That error message usually means that you have tried to add more columns to a row than you have defined.

Comment: @Maryam you probably have `\label` in the wrong place, put it inside the argument to `\caption` (or more or less anywhere except just before `\multicolumn`) But unless you make a proper example hard to say.

Comment: @ David just updated with the example.

Comment: @Maryam updated answer with your document

Comment: @ David Thanks, but the characters (e, f, o,..) don't appear on the top of the numbers. I mean the first row and the rest don't fit.

Comment: @ David- How I can make it smaller please? I used \footnotesize, but it affects the rest of document.

Comment: I solved it, I use \normalsize after finishing the table.

Comment: @Maryamas longtable warns you on the terminal and the log file column widths are fixed on later latex runs

Answer (score 1):

For "continued from previous page" and  the like, you can declare at the befginning of the longtable environment the contents of the first head (resp. general head)  and  the general foot (resp. the last foot).

Here is how. I used the `booktabs` package, and replaced the vertical line that separates the two series of columns with a 2 em wide white space. I also used `cellspace` to have a less tight vertical spacing of rows. I loaded the `ltablex` package, as it loads `longtable` and `mutirow` and extends the capabilities of longtable to the tabularx environment. If you should decide to use such a ‘longtabularx’ environment, all you have to do is replacing "longtable"  with "tabularx" and the `Sc` qualifier with `S{X}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = bf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3.5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{*{7}{Sc}@{\hskip 3em}*{7}{Sc}}
\caption{State Table for the proposed network}
 \label{table: state table proposed net.}\\
\multicolumn{14}{c}{$ n=0 $} \\
\toprule
e & f & o & h & c & g & r & E & F & O & H & C & G & R \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{14}{l}{\small continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
e & f & o & h & c & g & r & E & F & O & H & C & G & R \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{r}{\small to be continued}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%1
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%2
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%3
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%4
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%5
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%6
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%7
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%% 8
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%9
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%10
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%11
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%12
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%13
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%14
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%15
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ & $K_{e}$ \\
%%%%%%%16
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Bernard- Thanks, this gives me an error:  LaTeX Error: Command `\Gamma' already defined.

..             
                                                  
l.63 ...ymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{otherletters}{000} I even can't see \Gamma...

Comment: @Maryam: I suspect it's a conflict with the fourier package. Did you load other fonts (like `amsfonts`, &c.)? Anyway loading fourier and heuristica is here only because I prefer them to Computer Modern, you can comment them.

Comment: @Bernard You shouldn't use packages such as `fourier` and `heuristica` in examples. It's only confusing.

Comment: @egreg: you're right, I shouldn't. I supposed people would understand the choice of fonts is (usually) unessential, and I'm really fed up  with all those documents that look alike.